# Multisite - display the translation status in the entries list

Tags: multi-site

I have a main website with lot of articles and still growing. I would like to translate all articles into another language, so I created another site. Our process is not to save the entry to the other site automatically, when created, but *Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to*, once the entry in main site is ready to go.

The problem is, that I don't see which entries has been translated to the other language and saved to the other site already in the Entries Listing Page, only in the Entry Detail Page. Since there are more than thousand articles, It's a pain to click on every entry to find it out.

**Is there an option to display which sites the entry has been saved to on the Entries Listing Page?**

Thank a lot.